# How do I use a PyGame timer event? How to add a clock to a pygame screen using a timer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, clock

I'm new to python and therefore decided to try to make a simple game in `pygame`. I want to add a timer/clock that shows how long "you have played/survived", so creating a clock basically.

However, I've searched around and gotten the `time.sleep(1)` function and it does indeed work as a clock, but it slows down everything else of the game to the point it barely moves.

Is there a simple way to add a clock to the gamescreen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of milliseconds since `pygame.init()` can be retrieved by [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks). See [`pygame.time`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) module.

---

Furthermore in pygame exists a timer event. Use [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to repeatedly create an [`USEREVENT`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html). e.g.:

```py
time_delay = 500 # 0.5 seconds
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event , time_delay )
```

Note, in pygame customer events can be defined. Each event needs a unique id. The ids for the user events have to start at `pygame.USEREVENT`. In this case `pygame.USEREVENT+1` is the event id for the timer event.

Receive the event in the event loop:

```py
running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

         elif event.type == timer_event:
             # [...]
```

The timer event can be stopped by passing 0 to the time parameter.

---

See the example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)

counter = 0
text = font.render(str(counter), True, (0, 128, 0))

time_delay = 1000
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, time_delay)

# main application loop
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == timer_event:
            # recreate text
            counter += 1
            text = font.render(str(counter), True, (0, 128, 0))

    # clear the display
    window.fill((255, 255, 255))

    # draw the scene
    text_rect = text.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center)   
    window.blit(text, text_rect)

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: @Mokoisa Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn’t quite understand this.
Above the while loop I have:
time_delay = 1000 # 1 second
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
time = pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, time_delay)

def show_time(x, y):
    time_s = font.render("Time: " + str(time), True, (0, 0, 255))
    screen.blit(time_s, (x, y))

and tried to use “show_time” in the while loop as shown on your picture, but I get “None” instead of a timer when running the game. Am I missing a “pygame.time.get_ticks()” ?
Do you know where I've messed? Sorry, but I found this difficult.   Thanks again! :)

Comment: Im also new to these kind of websites, so sorry if my posts are messy af.

Comment: @Mokoisa See the example, which I've add to the answer, right now.