# Is clock.schedule_interval() valid in pygame or only pygame zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pgzero

I'm following a tutorial that involves pygame zero and adapting it to create a pygame program, but am haing issues with my timer.  The time_left variable is set to 10 earlier, here is the rest of the code to do with the timer:

```
def update_time_left():
    global time_left

    if time_left:
        time_left = time_left - 1
    else:
        game_over()
    
clock.schedule_interval(update_time_left, 1.0)
```

will the clock.schedule_interval() part work in pygame?  And if not is there anything else I can use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`schedule_interval` doesn't exist in pygame. See [`pygame.time`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) module. `schedule_interval` it is a method of the class `Clock` in pygame zero. See [Pygame Zero - Built-in Objects](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtins.html).

In pygame you can create a timer event. See the answers to the question [Python 3.8 pygame timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944795/python-3-8-pygame-timer/59944869#59944869) or [Countdown timer in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720665/countdown-timer-in-pygame/63551239#63551239).

Answer (score 0):

The pygamezero docs lie. The second parameter in schedual_interval is in ms, not sec.

If you want a 1 sec delay, use 1000

I figured this out the hard way :(